# misaligned table from txt file to panda dataframe

Tags: python, text-mining

I am trying to put a table from a text file to dataframe. The text file was created from a pdf.I am relatively new to python. I have a function that can handle a particular format of a text table. For example my code can handle when the second column only has MU../All uses/All/MU and no other text and the fourth column is smaller in length than the fifth. It can also handle if the first column has LM../(LM..)/3333(only digits) but without indentation.But this seems to be a little too hard for me. Because the second column could have sentences and words other than mentioned before and in one row the fourth column is longer than fifth and in another the first column has indentation. I am stuck with this.

```
LM1111      MU1111  Dev      text1 text1 text1 text1   medium
                                   text2 text2 text2 text2   text3 text3 
                                                         Text4 text4 

 (LM2222)   text5 text5   Val,dev   text7 text7 text7         low. Text10 
           Text6 text6             text8 text8 text8         text11 text11 
                                   Text9 text9 text9 

           MU2222       Val      text12 text12 text12       high
 3333      MU3333                   text13 text13 text13
```

The final dataframe should have 5 columns  and 3 rows as below

```
LM1111      MU1111       Dev       text1 text1 text1 text1   medium
                                   text2 text2 text2 text2   text3 text3 
                                                             Text4 text4 

(LM2222)   text5 text5   Val,dev   text7 text7 text7         low. Text10 
           Text6 text6             text8 text8 text8         text11 text11 
                                   Text9 text9 text9 

3333.       MU2222        Val      text12 text12 text12      high
            MU3333                 text13 text13 text13
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Note: 'text..' can be any sentence/multiple lines of sentences, words, numeric or special characters. I have been trying out all solutions posted on stackoverflow, tried tabula-py, pypdf2, pdfminer. Nothing seems to help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please put your code in the question, and describe precisely, what errors or other unwanted behaviour you get when executing it.